# Does this trig equation have a closed-form solution?

Tags: gm.general-mathematics

This equation came up when I was looking at the Fibonacci sequence; I adore its symmetry:

$$x^2 \cdot \sin \left(\frac{2\pi}{x-1} \right) \cdot \left(3+2 \cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{x} \right) \right) = (x-1)^2 \cdot \sin \left(\frac{2\pi}{x} \right) \cdot \left(3+2 \cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{x-1} \right) \right)$$

> **Question.** The largest solution is ~3.1392. Is there an closed-form expression for this number?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "analytic form". Also, your question does not belong to algebraic geometry, so I removed this tag.

Comment: I get $+3.1392$.  I see no reason that this should be expressed in terms of known numbers.